# Opening specific email causes Mail to crash

Tags: ios, email, mobile-mail

I have set up Microsoft Office Mail on my iPhone 6. The only problem that I cannot get my head round is that it all works fine but I received an email this morning, and when I clicked on it to read it, the screen just went back to the home page. All other emails I have received are fine and can open and be read no problem, but for this one email every time I try to open it the screen continues to go to the home screen.

Comment: Your title should be relevant to the actual problem you are facing. A nondescript title obfuscates the content of the question. I've edited the title to be more specific but feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

When the screen goes back to the home page, it means that Microsoft Office Mail is crashing because of some problem.

In this case, the email that you're trying to open contains something that causes the app to crash. This is an issue with Microsoft Office Mail, and not with your iPhone. The only solution right now is to either open this email on your computer, or wait for Microsoft to fix this bug in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

The email probably contains some kind of file that your phone doesn't know how to handle, or it could contain some kind of virus.  If you're sure it isn't, then try opening it on a different device.